# How to get the id of a third generated div in a complex structure using jQuery or just javascript?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div structure over which generation I have little control, generated by a jQuery function. The structure has 19 first generation children, one second generation child and 3 third generation children. I am not interested in the fourth generation children. Here is the code:

```
<div id="columntableordersGrid">
<div></div>
<div></div>
....
<div></div>
<div id="30bcef39-6ab1-69f5-81af-bbb9e870bfd4">
    <div>
        <div id="pdfs"><img src="/kabinet/images/32x32/pdf.png"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="filtericon">
                <div class="filterbutton"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sortasc">
                <div class="sortascbutton"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sortdesc" >
                <div class="sortdescbutton"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bb29c057-acd8-f1eb-aa13-69d8498ae47e">
            <div class="column-menubutton"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to get the id of one of the third generation children of this structure (bb29c057-acd8-f1eb-aa13-69d8498ae47e). Each time the script runs it is generating new ids.

I can get the ids of the first generation children by using:

```
    var all = $("#columntableordersGrid > div").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
```

I am interested in child 17, therefore all[16] gives me the id of that child, which is:

30bcef39-6ab1-69f5-81af-bbb9e870bfd4 in the code example above.

The second generation div has unfortunately no class or id, as I said, I have no control over its generation. The third child of this div is the one whose id I need.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id you need is always the parent of an element with the class ".column-menubutton" than the below should work using your existing code.

```
var parentDivId = all[16];
var menuParentDivId = $('#' + parentDivId + " .column-menubutton").parent().attr('id');
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jt9BW/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple selector like this to grab the 17th div (the index begins at 0, so 16 will grab the 17th div) and then get the ID of the first div found inside that div.

```
$('#columntableordersGrid div:eq(16) div:first').attr('id');
```

If the div you are interested in is always the last div (as it appears to be from the example above), you could simplify it slightly by doing:

```
$('#columntableordersGrid div:last div:first').attr('id');
```